# combine hashmaps of Arrays into array using stream API

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have a map to a map of Integers and I want filter for a key to the second map and combine the arrays for the giving key.

so basically I want to go from

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>
```

to

```
List<Integer>
```

For example

```
KeyA -> keya -> [1,2,3]
KeyB -> keya -> [4,5,6]
KeyC -> keyb -> [7,8]
```

The result should be if the filter value is keya [1,2,3,4,5,6], I don't really care about the first set of keys.

I don't have any issues completing this operation in a standard way of iterating.

I would like to use Streams though.

Comment: Is it `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>>
` or `Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>>`?  Rewrite example

Comment: I edited the question solution from Dmitrii worked just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some mistake in your description, you can't have two same keys named `"keya"` in the Map.
But, common solution by Stream API will looks like that:

```
    List<Integer> collect = source.values().stream()
            .flatMap(s -> s.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(s1 -> s1.getKey().equals(1) || s1.getKey().equals(2)) //needed key here
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

for example:

```
    Map<String, Map<Integer, List<Integer>>> source = Map.of("keyA", Map.of(1, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5)), "keyB", Map.of(2, Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8)));
```

Output:

**[5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 5]**

Comment: Just wanna add that the comment about key named "keya" is not accurate.

Answer (score 1):

If the keys of the inner map should be filtered, this can be done like this:

```java
static List<Integer> findByKey(Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> map, String key) {
    return map.values()
              .stream() // Stream<Map<String, List<Integer>>>
              .flatMap(v -> v.entrySet().stream()) // Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>>
              .filter(e -> key.equals(e.getKey()))
              .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()) // Stream<Integer>
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Test

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> map = Map.of(
    "KeyA", Map.of("keya", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)),
    "KeyB", Map.of("keya", Arrays.asList(4, 5, 6)),
    "KeyC", Map.of("keyb", Arrays.asList(7, 8))
);

System.out.println(findByKey(map, "keya"));
```

Output changes randomly

```
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
or 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

This output occurs randomly the mixed order, because the input map is not sorted and this can be resolved by sorting the stream of entrySet of the input map:

```java
static List<Integer> findByKeySorted(Map<String, Map<String, List<Integer>>> map, String key) {
    return map.entrySet()
              .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Map<List<Integer>>>>
              .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
              .map(e -> e.getValue().get(key)) // Stream<List<Integer>>
              .filter(Objects::nonNull)
              .flatMap(List::stream) // Stream<Integer>
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

System.out.println(findByKeySorted(map, "keya"));
```

Output (stable):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
List<Integer> list = m
                .values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(innerMap ->
                        innerMap
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(1))
                        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```